# Sprite not updating on collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, collision

Can someone explain why this code is not working as intended? Currently if there is a collision the sprite (flag) changes to green. The debug statements are working as I would expect but the sprite (flag) is not changed back to red in the event of no collision.

```
public Sprite gflag;
public Sprite rflag;
public SpriteRenderer render;
public GameObject Player;
private Checkpoint checkpoint;
private bool hit = false;

void Update()
{
    if(hit != true)
    {
        Debug.Log("False!");
        render.sprite = rflag;
    }
}

// Modify color of flag depending on collision
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("True!");
        render.sprite = gflag;
        hit = true;
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the checkpoint prefab:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your inspector for the flag?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post.

Comment: Why not just have the flag change to red in the OnTriggerExit2D and remove the logic from the update entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered moving the logic in the `Update()` function to a `OnTriggerExit2D` function?

```
public Sprite gflag;
public Sprite rflag;
public SpriteRenderer render;
public GameObject Player;
private Checkpoint checkpoint;
private bool hit = false;

// Modify color of flag depending on collision
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("True!");
        render.sprite = gflag;
        hit = true;
    }
}

// Modify color of flag depending on collision
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("False!");
        render.sprite = rflag;
        hit = false;
    }
}
```

This way, instead of checking in `Update` every frame, it will be handled within the collision functions entirely.

EDIT: To answer your initial question, the reason the code was not updating the flag back to red in the case of no collision is because you were not setting the `hit` boolean to `false` once the collision was exited.